# gconftool-2 doesn't refresh with the dbus anymore?

Tags: debian, command-line, gnome, configuration, d-bus

I used to use `gconftool-2` to edit keys in this way (here I change the cursor shape in gnome-terminal):

```
gconftool --type string --set /apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/Profile0/cursor_shape ibeam
```

But it doesn't work anymore, and I feel like there is a problem with the DBus daemon, even though I can't explain why.

This command *does* change the key in the `~/.gconf/.../Profile0/%gconf.xml`, where I can now read:

```
<entry name="cursor_shape" mtime="1419267709" type="string">
    <stringvalue>ibeam</stringvalue>
</entry>
```

But it has no effect on my cursor shape anymore: it is still a `block`.

Now, here is an interesting fact: if I use `gconf-editor` and navigate to this key, I find it set to `block`.

[image]

And if I now edit this key with the gui, it does change my cursor shape.

Everything behaves like the keys stored in memory and the keys stored in the .xml files are not updated together with the `gconftool-2` command.

I also noticed that `gconftool-2 --ping` doesn't return anything.

I have tried reinstalling `gconf2 gconf2-common gconf-service gconf-default-service` with no success. I also tried erasing the whole ~/.gconf folder, but the same thing keeps happening.

I have had a look at `gsettings` but my gnome-terminal doesn't seem to be supported with it since the schema `org.gnome.terminal` doesn't exist and since I can't find any folder `gnome-terminal` nor `gnome/terminal` under `dconf-editor`.

This is driving me mad, did it happen to anyone? How is the `gconftool-2` supposed to refresh and get instant changes in the running apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it! Credits to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/135579/338131). I added the following lines to my `.zshrc` or `.bashrc`:

```
sessionfile=`find "${HOME}/.dbus/session-bus/" -type f`
export `grep "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" "${sessionfile}" | sed '/^#/d'`
```

And the settings are now refreshed as soon as I use `gconftool-2`.